# Get the selected component from a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am dynamically adding items to my JPanel through an `ArrayList<Items>`. Basically the items object looks like that:

```
public class Item {

    private JComponent component;
    private String functionality;

    public Item(JComponent component, String functionality) {
        super();
        this.component = component;
        this.functionality = functionality;
    }

    public JComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    public void setComponent(JComponent component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public String getFunctionality() {
        return functionality;
    }

    public void setFunctionality(String functionality) {
        this.functionality = functionality;
    }
}
```

Here I am adding my buttons dynamically: (try the example out if you want)

```
public class minimumExample extends JFrame {

    private JButton addItem;

    private JComboBox itemBox;

    private String[] itemSelect = { "test1", "test2" };

    private JPanel addUpperPane;

    private JPanel addLowerPane;

    private ArrayList<Item> displayedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

    private JButton upButton;

    private JButton downButton;

    private JButton deleteButton;

    public void createControlPane() {

        addUpperPane = new JPanel();
        addLowerPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        addItem = new JButton("Add item");
        upButton = new JButton("Up");
        downButton = new JButton("Down");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");

        itemBox = new JComboBox(itemSelect);

        addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(itemBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("test1")) {
                    displayedItems.add(new Item( new ButtonComp().butt(), "test1"));                
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }

                if(itemBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("test2")) {
                    displayedItems.add(new Item( new LabelComp().label(), "test2"));    
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < displayedItems.size(); i++) {
                    addLowerPane.add(displayedItems.get(i).getComponent());
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });



        addUpperPane.add(itemBox, BorderLayout.EAST);
        addUpperPane.add(addItem, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(new JLabel(" | "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(upButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(downButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(deleteButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL));

        //put everything together

        add(addUpperPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(addLowerPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        repaint();

    }

    private void makeLayout() {

        setTitle("Test App");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));

        createControlPane();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }


    /**
     * starts the GUI
     */
    public void start() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                makeLayout();   
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        minimumExample ex = new minimumExample();
        ex.start();
    }



    public class ButtonComp extends Component {

        public JPanel butt() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            JButton button = new JButton("Test1");
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();

            panel.add(button);
            panel.add(check);

            return panel;
        }
    }

    public class LabelComp extends Component {

        public JPanel label() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Test2");
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();

            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(check);

            return panel;
        }
    }
}
```

The program basically looks like that:

[image]

My problem is that the buttons `Up, Down and Delete` do not work, because I do not know how to get the selected element from the pane to delete it from the list where all components are in. Any recommendations on how to make this work?

I really appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

I changed my code your specifications @cghislai but it does not work. Try it out yourself:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class minimumExample extends JFrame {

    private JButton addItem;

    private JComboBox itemBox;

    private String[] itemSelect = { "test1", "test2" };

    private JPanel addUpperPane;

    private JPanel addLowerPane;

    private List<CheckableItem> displayedItems = new ArrayList<CheckableItem>();

    private JButton upButton;

    private JButton downButton;

    private JButton deleteButton;

    public void createControlPane() {

        addUpperPane = new JPanel();
        addLowerPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        addItem = new JButton("Add item");
        upButton = new JButton("Up");
        downButton = new JButton("Down");
        deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");

        itemBox = new JComboBox(itemSelect);

        addItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(itemBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("test1")) {
                    ButtonComp butt = new ButtonComp();
                    butt.init();
                    displayedItems.add(butt);
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }

                if(itemBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("test2")) {
                    //                  displayedItems.add(new CopyOfItem( new LabelComp(), "test2"));  
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < displayedItems.size(); i++) {
                    addLowerPane.add(displayedItems.get(i).getComponent());
                    validate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });


        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                Iterator<CheckableItem> it = displayedItems.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    CheckableItem next = it.next();
                    if (next.isSelected()) {
                        addLowerPane.remove(next.getComponent());
                        it.remove();
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        addUpperPane.add(itemBox, BorderLayout.EAST);
        addUpperPane.add(addItem, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(new JLabel(" | "), BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(upButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(downButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(deleteButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        addUpperPane.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL));

        //put everything together

        add(addUpperPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(addLowerPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        repaint();

    }

    private void makeLayout() {

        setTitle("Test App");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 500));

        createControlPane();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }


    /**
     * starts the GUI
     */
    public void start() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                makeLayout();   
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        minimumExample ex = new minimumExample();
        ex.start();
    }




    public abstract class CheckableItem {

        protected JCheckBox check;

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return check.isSelected();
        }

        public abstract Component getComponent();

    }

    public class ButtonComp extends CheckableItem {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        public void init() {
            JButton button = new JButton("Test1");
            check = new JCheckBox();
            panel.add(button);
            panel.add(check);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponent() {
            return panel;
        }

    }

    public class LabelComp extends JPanel {

        public void label() {
            //          JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Test2");
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();

            add(label);
            add(check);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Component, is that AWT Component? Or your own custom class?

Comment: I assume that the `JCheckBox` is suppose to be used to "select" an item?  If so, create yourself a custom component which has a method called, something like `isSelected`.  Create instances of the component as you need and use the `isSelected` method to determine the "selected" state of the components

Comment: @OliverWatkins Its an AWT Component!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thx for your answer! Yes with the checkbox I would like to select the components that should go one slot up for example or get deleted. I would like to delete the component directly from the `ArrayList<Items>` because I use this later on my components. Any recommendations on how I could delete directly from the `ArrayList<Items>`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer In your proposed solution I would just determine if the instance of the component is selected or not. This would propably work with delete, but how could I put it upwards or downwards, if I do not know its exact "location" in the `ArrayList<Items>`?

Comment: missed notifier JPanel.revalidate() & JPanel.repaint() in both answers here, they aren't answers to your question

Comment: You can use indexOf from ArrayList to determine the index of a given object. Besides, in order to determine of a panel is selected, you'd need to iterate over the list, using a for-next loop would allow you to maintain the index reference ;)

Comment: Beware of mixing heavyweight (AWT) components a lightweight (Swing) components...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse all your items, check if the item checkbox is selected, if this is the case, remove your item from the panel. I would make an abstract CheckableItem class with a getter to the JCheckbox and the Component. Then, for each of you item, if the checkbox is selected, remove the component from the parent.

```
public abstract class CheckableItem {
    protected JCheckbox checkbox;
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return checkbox.isSelected();
    }
    public abstract Component getComponent();
}
public class ButtonComp extends CheckableItem {
    private Panel panel;
    public void init() {
        checkbox = new JCheckbox;
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(checkbox);
    }
    public Component getComponent() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Then to keep track of your items:

```
 private List<CheckableItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
    ButtonComp comp = new ButtonComp();
    comp.init();  
    items.add(comp);
```

Then to remove all checked:

```
Iterator<CheckbleItem> it = items.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    CheckableItem next = it.next();
    if (next.isSelected()) {
        mainPanel.remove(next.getComponent());
        it.remove();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer! At the moment you put your code of the components into a constructor. Could you change it into a method void method and add it to the list. I really would appreciate that, to accept your answer!

Comment: The thing is that you used the constructor to instantiate the component: `public ButtonComp() {
        checkbox = new JCheckbox;
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JButton());
        panel.add(checkbox);
    }
` However I would like to put it into a method and add it to the arrayList. But my problem is that I do not know how to do that...

Comment: Update my answer to move initialization in another function. I also update the item removal part to use iterator s you can remove while traversing the array.

Comment: I also updated my implementation with your code. However, this does not work... I really apprecaite your answer, so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just have your **ButtomComp** and **LabelComp** extend from JPanel? This would solve a lot of your problems I think. For example :

```
public class ButtonComp extends JPanel {

    JButton button;
    JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();


    public ButtonComp() {

        button = new JButton("Test1");

        this.add(button);
        this.add(check);
    }
}
```

Then all you would need to do is iterate over your items and look at the checkbox in the components :

```
for (int i = 0; i < displayedItems.size(); i++) {

    if (displayedItems.get(i).check.isSelected()) {
        displayedItems.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Note: haven't tested this code. But you should get the idea.

Comment: Thx for your answer! How would you solve the upwards and downwards issue, so moving one panel 1 up and 1 down? How do you get `check`?

Comment: thats a bit more complicated. But it is no longer a Swing issue. Its just plain arrayList manipulation. If you have more than one checkbox checked, then you are going to run into a number of issues.

Comment: Btw is the check in `displayedItems.get(i).check.isSelected()) ` also a field in my items class or how do you get this value?

Comment: it is the JCheckbox in your ButtonComp or your LabelComp. You probably need a super class for both ButtonComp and LabelComp like the other answer below.